# replace the submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I tried to implement a file upload process in my grid.
I chose to use the jquery.iframe-post-form plugin.
Most solutions post the data of the form and after the upload file.
In order to post all data of a form at once (Lastname, ...) + photo, I replaced the submit button of the form (sData) by mine.

```
$(formid).removeAttr('onsubmit');
$(formid).iframePostForm({ ... });
```

I attached code to this new button (click event). I changed the submit button id , so jqGrid will not attach its click event .

```
$('#sData').attr('id', 'mysubmit')               
           .click(function(e)
           { 
             ...
             $(formid).submit();
           })
```

Therefore I changed the behaviour of jqgrid: no beforeSubmit event, no afterSubmit event, no afterComplete event !

How to fire after all the afterSubmit event for getting back errors ?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand why you need to change `id` of edit form. What exactly is your goal? The description "to post all data at once" is not clear enough for me. What data you need to post (full data of editing row, full grid data and so on)?

Comment: Dear Oleg: I changed my wording ...

Comment: If you search [form editing module](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.5.2/js/grid.formedit.js) of jqGrid code for `#sData` text you will find many places. So changing of `id` from `"sData"` to `mysubmit` could break many parts of jqGrid code. I don't know `jquery.iframe-post-form` plugin, so I can't give you simple suggestion how to implement what you need.

Comment: Other solutions welcome ;-)

Answer (score 1):

How about just overriding the default behavior of the button?
Do your custom stuff the submit the form?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $(":button").click(function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 //Do Stuff then submit the form
                $('form').submit();

             });
});
```